# how to wrap flex items that scroll horizontally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I got the challenge to have flex items with a base of 140px. They cannot be shorter, therefore the will scroll horizontally in a overflow auto container.

The crux is, I want to wrap all the flex-items with a box-shadow. Unfortunately the wrapper wont wrap around all the flex-items and will stay as short as the overflow auto container.

The Outer-Wrapper is flexible but for the sake of this example fix to 400px;

here is the pen:

https://codepen.io/shooby83/pen/QWbJwaK

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  height: 100px;
  margin: 15px
}

.item {
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  background: pink;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">item one</div>
    <div class="item">item two</div>
    <div class="item">item three</div>
    <div class="item">item four</div>
    <div class="item">item five</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @G-Cyrillus no, then I wouldn't have a scrollable row anymore

Answer (score 0):

use `inline-flex` instead of `flex` and consider `width` instead of `flex-basis`

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width:calc(100% - 30px); /* to make sure it keep a block behavior when there is few items*/
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  height: 100px;
  margin: 15px
}

.item {
  width:100px;
  flex-grow:1;
  flex-shrink:0;
  background: pink;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">item one</div>
    <div class="item">item two</div>
    <div class="item">item three</div>
    <div class="item">item four</div>
    <div class="item">item five</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">item one</div>
    <div class="item">item two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```